# How to push notification from aws to windows desktop application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, windows

I am exploring ways to push notification to windows desktop application when there is change in the s3 bucket .
I am aware that I should be using WNS along with SNS NOT But clear on details .

Any suggestion would be helpful.
Please suggest if there is any other approach to solve this problem.

Comment: SNS -> WNS is the best solution. IF you dont want, you can implement for your own. For example: `S3 event -> Lambda -> your implemented service on Windows Server`

Comment: Thank you for the reply .I am aware that I should be using WNS along with SNS NOT But clear on details .Could you provide me some references.

Comment: Here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-wns.html

Comment: How about using MQTT ?

Comment: How about using AWS IoT (MQTT) ?

Comment: If you can implement with it, its ok too!

Comment: The documentation says that WNS+AWS supports with only windows 8 and above. Is there any work around for windows 7?